# How to get an event to occur if two different keys are pressed (HTML5 Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, keyevent

Basically I want my character to jump if I press any button on the keyboard, is there a way to make it do this using "case..." functions?
Thank you

Jordan

Comment: yes there is, try it!

Comment: Pay us money , we will code for you!! No questions asked!! Or else, try to search Google..

Comment: Okay...what is it? 
Jordan

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener to the body or to the canvas element.
Inspect the evt object in your console to see al its properties. it has for example ctrlKey and altKey pressed as a property which is probaly what you are looking for.

```
document.body.addEventListener('keydown',function(evt) {
e = evt || window.event;
var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
if (charCode > 0) {
  console.log("key pressed = "+ charcode);
  console.log(e);
}
});
```